# JQuery Chosen plugin - get ID of selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using the Chosen plugin in MVC razor and need to get the selected item id in onchange event:

```
<optgroup label="@col">
    foreach (String[] colSub in sList)
        {                                            
           <option id="@colSub[1]" class="opts">@colSub[0]</option> 
        }
</optgroup>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#chosen').on('change', function (evt, params) {
     var selectedOption = params.selected; //gives me the selectedOption = @colSub[0]
     var id = //i need the id here  
}
```

In the above i need the ID also?

Comment: Still looking for answer

Answer (score 3):

<s>You can simply use</s>

```
$('#chosen').on('change', function (evt, params) {
     var id = $(this).find('option:selected').prop('id');
});
```

You can use use `.map()` to generate array of selected IDs

```
$("#chosen").on('change', function (evt, params) {
    var SelectedIds = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function () {
        return $(this).prop('id')
    }).get();
    console.log(SelectedIds);
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/S4tQf/)

Comment: Satpal sorry the above does not work as multiple options can be selected and the above breaks on option:selected. To get the selected option use params.selected. But now how to get the id??

Comment: An adaptation of this code snippet fixed a similar problem for me. Thanks for the answer. :)